# How can I style :visited <a> elements that use React's onClick="" instead of href=""?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

- The website has a table.
- In the table, I get data from the Firestore (and display this data to the user). Some cells in the table may link to other pages on the site (which are also implemented as a table).

Since there is a lot of information, the user can get confused which links they followed and which they have not touched; thus, I would like to mark with a different color when hovering over those links that the user has already visited.

By default, my link color is black, and if you hover over the link, it lights up blue. I would like the links visited by the user to be highlighted in a different color.

Below is an example of how I write the route

```js
export default function DeviceCell({ device }) {
    const router = useNavigate()

    return (
        <TableRow>
          
            <TableCell>
                <a className="page-links" onClick={() => router(device.id)}>List of users</a>
            </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    );
}
```

Also my .css file

```css
.page-links {
    color: #3A3A3F;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px black solid;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;   
}
    
.page-links:hover {
   color: #485FED;
   border-bottom: 1px #485FED solid;
   border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

Comment: _"Perhaps because I use a firewall as a database"_ - ehh?

Comment: Use `a.page-links:visited:hover { color: red; }`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Comment: @Dai I fixed mistake with firewall, thank you :)

Comment: @Dai Of course I tried this option, but it does not suit me

Comment: @Paul _"but it does not suit me"_  - Well, it works, doesn't it? If you're having technical issues with it then **please be specific** - and you didn't mention anything about that in your post.

Comment: @Dai This code doesn't work for me. After clicking on the link, and returning to the page, when you hover over the link, it still lights up blue

Comment: What does your browser's dev-tools tell you about the `<a>` elements?

Comment: `:visited` only works for `<a href="">` links, but you have `<a onclick="">`, so `:visited` won't work for that. Is there a reason you're doing things this way?

Comment: @Dai Yes, I use <a onclick=""> because <a href=""> doesn't work in my case.

Comment: I've retitled your question to make it clear to everyone that `:visited` is not going to work.

Comment: If you are using some sort of centralized state manager (e.g. Redux) you could save the IDs of the visited device pages and set a CSS class to the link, according to whether the `device.id` is included in that list. Something like ``<a className={`page-links${idList.includes(device.id) ? ' visited' : ''}`}>``, then in the CSS `.page-links.visited:hover { color: red;}`

Comment: @secan Yes, this is close to what I'm looking for. But there is one nuance: when I follow the link and return to the previous page, then all device.id that are included in idList light up red. Can this be fixed in such a way that only the link under a specific device.id is red?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you want to achieve but shouldn't _all_ link already visited become red onMouseOver? If you want only the last visited one, instead of storing an array of all visited devices ID you can store only the last visited device ID and change from `idList.includes(device.id) ? ...` to `savedId === device.id ? ...`

Comment: Here you can see a quick example of the concept, _in "vanilla" JS_: https://jsfiddle.net/dtjsro81/

Comment: Just to be clear: I am not suggesting you use the sample code "as is"; it was intended just to illustrate the general idea without having to create all the react/redux environment boiler plate code. I am not going to add the code in the answer, as it is not the final solution to your question; it is just a general suggestion about how you can approach the problem but the actual implementation is left to you. ;)

Comment: `<a href="…">` should definitely work and mark links as visited with React Router. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else? Have you tried `<Link to="…">`?

Comment: @tobiv No, I have not tried this design.

Comment: Please explain in your question description why `<a href>` wouldn't work in your case. Because atm it seems you want to create some link history mechanism the browser already provides. E.g. `<a href="#">` (notice the hashtag) will not jump to another page, but will add an entry in the browser history log after the `<a>` has been clicked, therefore enabling the use of CSS for `:visited`. I ask for the explanation as I think *making* `<a href>` work seems the shortest route to go and has the least (less) maintenance. Currently your snippet only *invites us* to add a `href` to solve your problem.

Comment: @Rene van der Lende I am unable to use href instead of onClick. I don’t know what could be the reason: maybe because I don’t use pure HTML in my code, maybe because I use REACT and MUI, maybe because I take data from the firestore. I haven't been learning this language for a long time. As soon as I add href instead of onClick the whole app crashes

Comment: Not instead of, but in addition to. You obviously need the `onclick` trigger, so leave that structure intact. Simply insert `href="#"` into the `<a>` inside your function return. I can't imagine React messing that up, as it is fully legit and being used in millions of webpages to have some *focusable trigger*. The 'click' will be saved in the browser history and what you do with it when it fired is irrelevant...

Comment: Oh, then use `:visited` in your CSS... And, please, add your explanation to your description so people don't have to read all the comments to figure that out.

Comment: Dang, `useNavigate()` creates a `href` of some kind using `device.id` data, that's where things get messed up. This will override the `href="#"` I suggested. As the generated `href` link gets created each time, the browser 'thinks' the page has changed, it resets the history for that link each time to page loads. So, don't add `href` (sorry!) but try `router(device.id, { replace: true });` (replaces last history entry) and use CSS `:visited`. Read [React: useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate#usenavigate).

Comment: @Rene van der Lende Unfortunately, the version from the last message also does not work (

Comment: an `<a>` tag with an `onclick` handler but no `href` is an antipattern in and of itself. Step back and ask yourself - does this thing actually behave like a link, or a button? The difference is that a link goes to a different page a, whereas a button carries out some action on the current page. If this is a link, it should have an href, while if it's a button, it should use a `<button>` tag and your question goes away. Using the correct HTML tag will make your life easier as a developer and also ensure assistive technologies such as screenreaders behave the way their users would want them to.

Comment: Agreed with @RobinZigmond — there is no reason to use an <a> with an onClick here.  This should be a react-router <Link href=“”> element, which will create an <a> element in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to use :visited CSS pseudo selector, basically we have to create browser history because visited pseudo selector depends on it. Way to do it without creating real navigation with HTML anchor element is [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).
To solve this issue, we have to add symbolic href to our link for pushing history states and preventing default HTML link navigation event behaviour.

An appropriate example can be found on [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-visited-on-react-onclick-3m8h5b) and [sandbox preview](https://3m8h5b.csb.app/)

```
export default function DeviceCell({ device }) {
const router = useNavigate()
const handleClick = (e) => { 
   // Prevent default HTML Anchor Event
   e.preventDefault();
   window.history.pushState({ data: device.id }, `Data: ${device.id}`, e.target.href);
   router(device.id)
}
return (
    <TableRow>
      
        <TableCell>
            <a href={`/user/${device.id}`} className="page-links" onClick={handleCLick}>List of users</a>
        </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
)}
```

CSS:

```
a.page-links:hover:visited {
  background-color: #dc2626;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is something that is closest to my case. I just want to clarify why we define handleClick but don't use it anywhere else.

Comment: At the moment, if you add your code to mine, it turns out that when you click on a link to go to another page, the first page simply reloads

Comment: I corrected the mistakes now. The snippets I shared may not work with your code base because your stack is not well defined in your question. For example, I didn't know which router library you use. Are those libraries already have History API hooks etc. . You should understand the logic behind it. The sandbox I provided contains a working solution for your example. The basic logic is leveraging History API to use the visited pseudo selector. Sandbox includes clarifying comments and external references. I hope your problem will solve.

Comment: Incredible, this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. It's a pity that the bounty is over, and I can't reward you on merit

Comment: I'm glad your problem was solved. I'll take a look.

Comment: I found a small bug in this approach, maybe you can tell me how to solve it. The site has several pages: from the devices page (first page) you can go to the users page (second page), from the users page to the sessions page (third page) and so on. But if you go back (for example, from the third page) by pressing the "back" button in the browser, then immediately go to the first page (that is, the transition back is not sequential (as forward)). Do you know how to solve this problem?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Answer (score 4):

There are two scenarios based on your question as you said  "*After clicking on the link and returning to the page, when you hover over the link, it still lights up blue*"

> Do you want to preserve the clicked links in a single session?

- If that's the case, then you need to store your visited links somewhere on the browser like cookies or localStorage or SessionStorage and check against the list on render. If exists change the CSS else use the different one.
- You also need to have logic on the list size stored. How big it should be and how long it may be stored on the browser(expiration)

---

> Do you want the visited links to persist across multiple sessions?

- If that's the case then you need a bit of help from the server side as well. You need a mechanism to store the state on the backend (storage can be your choice - NoSql db, SQL db etc) and then check against the list for the specific user while rendering the page.
- You need a mechanism to identify users. If they are logged in, its easy and you can use their user id. If the users are anonymous, the either you can create a cookie to identify users or a different mechanism to generate a unique user id.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that cleared up a few issues. But it added a headache to my task :) Thank you for your advice

Comment: This is the proper way to do it

Answer (score -1):

`a.page-links:visited:hover { color: red;}`

Should work.

Comment: Thank you, but I wouldn't be asking this question if it was so obvious and simple.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible it's simply the ordering?

a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited in the CSS definition in order to be effective.

```
.page-links{
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px black solid;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    color: #3A3A3F;
    cursor: pointer;   
}

.page-links:visited { 
    color: red; 
} 

.page-links:hover{
    color: #485FED;
    border-bottom: 1px #485FED solid;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work either. The problem here is that I'm using <a onclick=""> and not <a href=""> as Dai pointed out

Answer (score -2):

Your problem can be solved by associating one more function that will change the color of the link when the user clicks on the link

```
onclick = existing-function; changeColor() => {
    document.this.style.color = "color";}
```

Use a semi-colon to separate the two functions.

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question. I'm sorry, but I didn't understand your idea. Could you show me this with my code?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).